# Java get item from String[] list

Tags: java

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Lehma {

    private static final String[] NAMES = new String[]{
    "Anu", "Arpa", "Essi", "Heluna", "Hely",
    "Hento", "Hilke", "Hilsu", "Hymy", "Matti", "Ilme", "Ilo",
    "Jaana", "Jami", "Jatta", "Laku", "Liekki",
    "Mainikki", "Mella", "Mimmi", "Naatti",
    "Nina", "Nyytti", "Papu", "Pullukka", "Pulu",
    "Rima", "Soma", "Sylkki", "Valpu", "Virpi"};

    private String name;
    private int volumes;


    public Lehma() {
        int index = new Random().nextInt(NAMES.length);
        // Get index item from NAMES list                     
    }     
}
```

How I can get specific index from NAMES string array? I tried to use some get methods, but it didn't work. For example if index is 1, then the return should be "Arpa" because Arpa's index is 1 in NAMES array.

Comment: `NAMES[index]`... please read a tutorial.

Comment: In java it's `array` not `list`..    We call it `list` in python

Answer (score 2):

Just use this syntax:-

If you wanna need value from index 0 then `NAMES[0]`

If you wanna need value from index 1 then `NAMES[1]`

If you wanna need value from index 2 then `NAMES[2]`

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public String getItem(String[] arr, int index) {
     return arr[index];
}
```